# Looking for author or title of this book with Earth, Mars, Revenants and chemically induced amnesia

Tags: story-identification, aliens, mars

The story is about a female star pilot who is attacked and wakes up to find the last three years of her life have been chemically wiped away.  She searches for information on her son (now dead) and on why her ship was attacked.

It involves trips to a space colony, to Mars and family/clans that were abandoned by earth, and to earth and the military trying to uncover who she carried, what the alien was carrying, and why she was attacked.  The secondary character is also an alien (Short, furry and very pragmatic.)